# Save a WAV file to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload, save

This is a web service call which I wrote that is intended to receive a WAV file via a POST and store it in the web-app server's local file system (IIS).  Is there a simple method to store the file and if so would someone be so kind as to provide a C# example?

Comment: Is the intent here to offer a proper web service, i.e. SOAP-based, or are you talking in generic terms about a service which happens to be on the web and is provided from a web page? If it's the latter then SLaks answer below is appropriate.

Comment: My first answer, not my second one

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have write access to the directory you want to save to.

Make a FileUpload control, then call its SaveAs method in a postback.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a REST service, use the following code:

```
Request.Files[0].SaveAs(/* some file path */);
```

Either way, be aware of the security issues - make sure the filename has a .wav extension and don't trust the file to be correct.